# Make permission errors of COCOS2dx

Tags: android-ndk, makefile, cygwin, cocos2d-x

### Environment

> OS:windows 7 64b, environmental:eclipse 4.2, cocos2dx 2.2.1, android
> ndkr9b, cygwin64

### Error content

```
Android NDK: WARNING:/cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x-2.2.1/cocos2d-x-2.2.1/projects/MyProject/proj.android/../../../cocos2dx/Android.mk:cocos2dx_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
[armeabi] Install        : libcocos2dcpp.so => libs/armeabi/libcocos2dcpp.so
make: execvp: install: Permission denied
make: *** [libs/armeabi/libcocos2dcpp.so] Error 127
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9b-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r9b/build/core/build-binary.mk:620: recipe for target 'libs/armeabi/libcocos2dcpp.so' failed
make: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x-2.2.1/cocos2d-x-2.2.1/projects/MyProject/proj.android'
```

I dont know why 'make execvp install' dont have permission.Please tell me who understand.

### Tryed it.

1. I have granted 777 permissions on the relevant file

For example,
libs/armeabi, libcocos2dcpp.so, build_native.sh

Comment: Check out the 9th step of the instruction given on this [LINK..](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Setup_the_cocos2d-x_for_android_in_Windows_8_Metro)

Comment: >Vivek Bansal

thank you!!

Comment: its ok ...you can upvote my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

(This question is answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@Vivek Bansal wrote:

> Check out the 9th step of the instruction given on this [LINK](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Setup_the_cocos2d-x_for_android_in_Windows_8_Metro)..

To avoid a link only answer, that link shows:

> 9. Set Permissions: The problem with the generated new project is that, 
>      it is generated using a different user in windows and our actual
>      login will not have access to copy or modify it. For this to work,
>      right click on the generated project folder ‘TestGame’ go to the
>      Security Tab, click Advanced and select the first option. Allow,
>      Everyone, Full Control, This folder subfolders and files. Screen shots
>      below. Also check the option ‘Replace all child object permission
>      entries with inheritable permission entries from this object’ This
>      will modify the permissions for all subfolders.